# How to increment a value which could be of either 1 or 2 or 3 decimal digits or without decimal values also?

Tags: regex, perl

I have to increment version number in a file. I could pattern match the version no. using following code in a particular string:

```
if($string =~ /versionName="(\d{1,3}+(\.\d{1,3})?)"/)
```

Now possibilities of having values are:
`1. x{1,3}.x{1,3}` (value having up to three decimal value or without decimal also)

Now I have to increment the value accordingly.

1. If it a value without decimal say 2 then I have to make it 3.
2. If it is a value having one decimal value say 3.2, then I have to make it 3.3 till 3.9, after that it should be incremented as 4.0
3. If it is a value having two decimal values say 4.22, then I have to make it 4.23 till 4.99, after that it should be incremented as 5.00
4. If it is a value having three decimal value say 56.554, then I have to make it 56.555 till 56.999, after that it should be incremented as 57.000

Please let me know if there is any confusion with the question.
I've not done this kind of thing before, so confused right now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you want to ignore the "." when doing the addition.

You can achieve that by multiplying by 10<sup>n</sup> where *n* is the number of decimal places before the addition, then by dividing by the same factor, but then you'd need to worry about floating-point precision error.

You can also achieve that by literally removing the "." from the string.

```
if (my ($unit, $frac) = $num =~ /^([^.]*)\.(.+)/s) {
    my $places = length($frac);
    $num = "$unit$frac" + 1;
    $num = sprintf('%0*d', $places+1, $num);  # Handle 0.x
    substr($num, -$places, 0, '.');
} else {
    ++$num;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. Code is working fine. But I am not from programming background. Can you please help me know how it is working ?

Comment: Removes the "." from the string. Adds one. Re inserts the "." in the string.

Comment: Thanks, got it after printing values and understanding functions !!

Answer (score 1):

Count the decimal number (1,2, 3) = C. Multiply by 10 exp C. Add one and then divide by 10expC.
Yep?

Example:

10.999

° multiply by 1000 = 10999

° add 1 = 11000

° divide by 1000 = 11.000

Comment: This may break going from 1.19 to 1.20 to 1.30. In other words, adding .01 to 1.19 may produce 1.2, not 1.20 for the regexp match.

Comment: That's why I wrote 11.000 as a previous result. It should keep the right decimal part.

Comment: Will it? `perl -e 'print ((10.999 * 1000 + 1)/1000)'` produces just `11` for me.

Comment: @Arkadiy, You'd need to end with a (s)printf to format the number.

Comment: Could you add sprintf to your answer?

Comment: @Arkadiy, It's not my answer, and the only implementation to which `sprintf` can be added is your own comment (which I cannot edit).

Comment: @ikegami: sorry, I thought I was talking to farvilian.

Comment: Thank to u 2 but there is a complete answer from ikegami

Answer (score 0):

If the version contains more than once decimal then we may have some problem ( Ex :- 10.9.9 which should result in 11.0.0 )

I have tried to write a perl snippet which should help

```
my $version="10 .9.9" ;
$version =~ s/\s+//g ;
my @ver_seg = split("",$version);
my $flag_incr=1;
for (my $i= @ver_seg-1; $i>0 && $flag_incr!=0 ; $i-- )
{
  if ( $ver_seg[$i] !~ /\./ )
  {
    my $temp=$ver_seg[$i];
    $temp=$temp+$flag_incr ;
    $flag_incr= $temp/10;
    $ver_seg[$i]=$temp%10;
  }
}

my $version_new=join("",@ver_seg);
print "hi $version_new \n";
```

taken an example with 10.9.9 .

Comment: Thanks for your concern, in my case it will be only like that I have mentioned. Means only like something 10.99 but never 10.9.9